# IF dentro de uma class

Tags: c#

sou novato em c#, e queria fazer o seguinte: Tenho a class dllimport que está sendo utilizada
em uma outra class. O problema é o seguinte, eu quero passar a constante(caminho da dll) de acordo com a versão 
do windows 64 ou 32. Tentei passar um metódo como parâmetro, mas não rolou e pelo que vi a class dllimport só
aceita argumento estático(ou constante). Alguém sabe como resolvo?
Segue meu código:

```
//const string DllName = "C:\\EZForecourt\\EZClient.dll";
public string DllName()
{

if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE") == "AMD64" || Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432") == "AMD64")
{
    return "C:\\EZForecourt\\EZClient64.dll";
}
else 
{
    return "C:\\EZForecourt\\EZClient.dll";
}

}    

//--------------------------------- Connection -----------------------------------------//

[DllImport(DllName, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
internal static extern Int32 ClientLogon(Int32 ClientID, Int16 ClientType, Int32 EventHandle, System.IntPtr hWnd, Int32 wMsg);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gonçalves, obrigado novamente pela ajuda, mas encontrei um modo mais simples de resolver. Eu coloquei uma diretiva:

```
 #if WIN64
   const string DllName = "\\EZForecourt\\EZClient64.dll";
 #else
   const string DllName = "\\EZForecourt\\EZClient.dll";
 #endif
```

Answer (score 3):

Eu passei por este mesmo problema um tempo atrás, pois desenvolvo para ambos os tipos, para resolver isso precisei adicionar ao meu projeto uma pasta "DLL" e nela adicionei ambos os tipos de `dll`.

[image: Imagem da pasta DLL]

Então procurei uma forma de poder resolver esse problema sempre carregando a `dll` correta ao iniciar a aplicação.

**Classe**

```
    public static class DLL_Loader
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Verifica a arquitetura do SO(32/64 bits) e carrega a dll correta para funcionamento das impressoras TSC.
        /// </summary>
        public static void TSC_DLL(string appLocation)
        {
            //string appLocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
            string dllLocation = Path.Combine(appLocation, @"Dll\TSC\TSCLIB_32B.dll");
            string newLocation = Path.Combine(appLocation, @"TSCLIB.dll");

            if (IntPtr.Size == 8) //No modo 32bit o IntPrt.Size será 4, já em 64bit será 8.
            {
                dllLocation = Path.Combine(appLocation, @"Dll\TSC\TSCLIB_64B.dll");
            }

            File.Copy(dllLocation, newLocation, true); //Gerar dll correta com o nome que preciso.
        }
    }
```

Para chamar ela:

```
DLL_Loader.TSC_DLL(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location));
```

Utilizo na classe `Program.cs` dos meus projetos `WindowsForm`.

Espero que possa te ajudar.